# How do I delete a question that has been labeled a duplicate?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked a question. It was put on hold. I rephrased the question but later decided to repost the edited question. It was flagged as a duplicate.
Now,  I would like to delete one of them.

How can I do that?

Comment: Under your question there should be a delete link. (next to share, edit, flag). As long as your question has no upvoted answer (or multiple answers) that should work.

Comment: see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222